# Django Model is creating another model after editing it

Tags: python, django

I made a random number creator in a model and if I make changes on an object Cakmak on the admin page, after saving it, it creates another one with the same name but different no.

```
from django.db import models
from random import randint


class Cakmak(models.Model):
    marka = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    model = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False, )

    def save(self):
        no = randint(100000, 999999)
        if Cakmak.objects.filter(no=no).exists():
            super(Cakmak, self).save()
        else:
            self.no = no
        super(Cakmak, self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.marka) + (' ') + (self.model)
```

Comment: It's a problem with multiple super().save calls. You have to return after the first super().save call.

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3 so should I make it a while loop with a break, if the object is exising?

Comment: No. Remove else, deindent self.no = no and change the if block as return super().save().